# How to update an element in AngularJS, without using routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi everybody i am currently doing the CRUD for a restaurant(school project), i can display all my elements from my API Rest, i can delete an element, also i can create new elements. But my problem is that i do not know how to update an element. I am using the $resource update, this is my code: 
Here i display my dishes, and hace 2 buttons, in the first button i get the id of that element.

```
<tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat = "dish in dishes | filter:sort">
         <td>{{dish.name}}</td>
         <td>{{dish.description}}</td>
         <td>{{dish.price | currency}}</td>
         <td>{{dish.category}}</td>
         <td>
            <button ng-click = "eliminarPlatillo(dish._id)" class = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle btn btn-danger"></button>
            <button ng-click = "modificarPlatillo(dish._id)" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#editarModal" class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btn btn-success"></button>
         </td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now when i clicked the element and got its id, in a modal i put the new data:

```
div id = "editarModal" class = "modal fade" role = "dialog">
        <div class = "modal-dialog">
            <div class = "modal-content">
                <div class = "modal-header">
                    <button type = "button" class = "close" data-dismiss = "modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class = "modal-title">Modificar Platillo</h4>
                </div>
                <div class = "modal-body">
                    <form role = "log" ng-submit = "modificarPlatillo()" ng-controller = "MenuController">
                        <div class = "form-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <input type = "text" name = "name" id = "name" placeholder = "Nombre" class = "form-control" ng-model = "form.name">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <input type = "number" name = "price" id = "price" placeholder = "Precio" class = "form-control" ng-model = "form.price">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                             <input type = "text" name = "category" id = "category" placeholder = "Categoria" class = "form-control" ng-model = "form.category">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <input type = "file" name = "image" id = "image" placeholder = "Imagen" class = "form-control" ng-model = "form.image">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <textarea class = "form-control" placeholder = "Descripción" name = "description" id = "description" ng-model = "form.description" rows = "5" cols = "10"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <button class = "btn btn-success" type = "submit">Aceptar</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In ng-submit i call my function to handle the update.
Now my controller for that function:

```
$scope.modificarPlatillo = function(index) {
        console.log($scope.index);
        $scope.dish = menuService.getPlatillos().get({id:index});
        console.log($scope.dish);
        menuService.getPlatillos().update({id: index});  
    };
```

i got an error saying this
    PUT http://localhost:3000/api//platillos 404 (Not Found), somehow it is true, because to delete an element you have to provide id, but i am doing that in my function.

Do you guys have a solution for my problem, how to use a modal and call the function.

Thank you in advance

Edit 1:

MenuService:

```
use strict';
angular.module("nightshift")
.constant("baseURL", "http://localhost:3000/api/")
.service("menuService", ["$resource", "baseURL", function($resource,    baseURL) {
    this.getPlatillos = function() {
        return $resource(baseURL + "/platillos/:id", null, {"update":{method:"PUT"}});
    };

    this.getPromociones = function() {
        return $resource(baseURL + "/promociones", null, {"update":{method:"PUT"}});
    }
}])
```

Controller:

```
"use strict";
angular.module("nightshift")
.controller("MenuController", ["$scope", "menuService",  function($scope, menuService) {
    var indice = 0;
    $scope.dishes = menuService.getPlatillos().query(
        function(response) {
            $scope.dishes = response;
        }, 
        function(response) {
            console.log("Error: " + response.statusText);
        }
    );

    $scope.form = {name: "", description: "", price: "", category: "", image: ""};

    $scope.agregarPlatillo = function() {
        console.log($scope.form);
        menuService.getPlatillos().save($scope.form);
        $scope.form = {name: "", description: "", price: "", category: "", image: ""};  
    };

    $scope.eliminarPlatillo = function(index) {
        $scope.dish = menuService.getPlatillos().get({id:index});
        console.log($scope.dish);
        console.log(index);
        menuService.getPlatillos().remove({id:index});
    };


    $scope.getIndex = function(index) {
        indice = index;
    }

    $scope.modificarPlatillo = function(index) {
        //console.log($scope.index);
        //$scope.dish = menuService.getPlatillos().get({id:index});
        //console.log($scope.dish);
        menuService.getPlatillos().$save($scope.form); 
    };
}])
```

And finally Platillos.html where i call my functions and display my elements:

```
div id="wrapper">

<div id = "platilloModal" class = "modal fade" role = "dialog">
        <div class = "modal-dialog">
            <div class = "modal-content">
                <div class = "modal-header">
                    <button type = "button" class = "close" data-dismiss = "modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class = "modal-title">Alta de Platillos</h4>
                </div>
                <div class = "modal-body">
                    <form role = "log" ng-submit = "agregarPlatillo()">
                        <div class = "form-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <input type = "text" name = "name" id = "name" placeholder = "Nombre" class = "form-control" ng-model = "form.name">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <input type = "number" name = "price" id = "price" placeholder = "Precio" class = "form-control" ng-model = "form.price">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                             <input type = "text" name = "category" id = "category" placeholder = "Categoria" class = "form-control" ng-model = "form.category">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <input type = "file" name = "image" id = "image" placeholder = "Imagen" class = "form-control" ng-model = "form.image">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <textarea class = "form-control" placeholder = "Descripción" name = "description" id = "description" ng-model = "form.description" rows = "5" cols = "10"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <button class = "btn btn-success" type = "submit">Agregar</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 


    <div id = "editarModal" class = "modal fade" role = "dialog">
        <div class = "modal-dialog">
            <div class = "modal-content">
                <div class = "modal-header">
                    <button type = "button" class = "close" data-dismiss = "modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class = "modal-title">Modificar Platillo</h4>
                </div>
                <div class = "modal-body">
                    <form role = "log" ng-submit = "modificarPlatillo()" ng-controller = "MenuController">
                        <div class = "form-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <input type = "text" name = "name" id = "name" placeholder = "Nombre" class = "form-control" ng-model = "form.name">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <input type = "number" name = "price" id = "price" placeholder = "Precio" class = "form-control" ng-model = "form.price">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                             <input type = "text" name = "category" id = "category" placeholder = "Categoria" class = "form-control" ng-model = "form.category">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <input type = "file" name = "image" id = "image" placeholder = "Imagen" class = "form-control" ng-model = "form.image">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <textarea class = "form-control" placeholder = "Descripción" name = "description" id = "description" ng-model = "form.description" rows = "5" cols = "10"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <button class = "btn btn-success" type = "submit">Aceptar</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 


<div id="page-wrapper">

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Page Heading -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">
                        Lista de Platillos
                    </h1>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="active">
                        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Platillos
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-sm-2">
                <button type = "button" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#platilloModal" class = "btn btn-primary"><span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Agregar Platillo</button>
            </div>
            <div class = "pull-right form-group has-feedback">
                <input type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder = "Buscar Platillo" ng-model = "sort">
                <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Descripción</th>
                            <th>Precio</th>
                            <th>Categoria</th>
                            <th>Acción</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat = "dish in dishes | filter:sort">
                            <td>{{dish.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{dish.description}}</td>
                            <td>{{dish.price | currency}}</td>
                            <td>{{dish.category}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button ng-click = "eliminarPlatillo(dish._id)" class = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle btn btn-danger"></button>
                                <button ng-click = "modificarPlatillo(dish._id)" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#editarModal" class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btn btn-success"></button>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$.save` as the element already contains the information on how to interact with the API therefore according to my experience should be the best practice approach. Is the one I use and works pretty well.

Edit 1:
This is how I normally handle API calls (always thru services)

```
app.service('UsersService', function ($q, API) {
    var self = {
        'isLoading': false,
        'editMode': false,
        'list': [],
        'selected': false,
        'load': function () {
            self.isLoading = true;
            API.users.get().$promise.then(function (data) {
                angular.forEach(data.list, function (user) {
                    self.list.push(new API.users(user));
                });
                self.isLoading = false;
            });
        }, 'create': function (user) {
            var d = $q.defer();
            API.users.save(user).$promise.then(function (data) {
                self.list = [];
                self.load();
                d.resolve();
            });
            return d.promise;
        }, 'read': function (id) {
            for (var i = 0; i < self.list.length; i++) {
                var obj = self.list[i];
                if (obj.id == id) {
                    return obj;
                }
            }
        }, 'update': function (user) {
            var d = $q.defer();
            user.$save({id: user.id}).then(function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < self.list.length; i++) {
                    var obj = self.list[i];
                    if (obj.id == data.id) {
                        self.list[i] = data;
                    }
                }
                d.resolve();
            });
            return d.promise;
        }, 'delete': function (user) {
            var d = $q.defer();
            user.$remove({id: contact.id}).then(function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < self.list.length; i++) {
                    var obj = self.list[i];
                    if (obj.id == data.id) {
                        self.list.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
                self.selected = {};
                d.resolve()
            });
            return d.promise;
        }
    };
    self.load();
    return self;
});
```

Edit 2:
And then, you can use them directly thru the controller just by injecting the service and adding your app logic (please note this is an example I have, which uses aditional modules and functions than you might need):

```
app.controller('UsersController', function ($stateParams, $translate, $state, $scope, $rootScope, ModalService, $element, UsersService, ClientsService, ngNotify) {
    $scope.Users = UsersService;
    $scope.Clients = ClientsService;

    $scope.filterDirectory = "";
    $scope.selectedClient = 0;

    //Check if the state params have changed
    if ($state.params.id > 0) {
        $scope.$watch('Users.isLoading', function (n, o) {
            if (!n) {
                $scope.Users.selected = $scope.Users.read($state.params.id);
            }
        });
    }

    $scope.editUser = function (id) {
        if (!angular.isUndefined(id)) {
            $scope.Users.editMode = true;
        } else {
            $scope.Users.editMode = false;
            $scope.Users.selected = "";
        }

        ModalService.showModal({
            templateUrl: "app/views/users/editUser.modal.html",
            controller: "UsersController"
        }).then(function (modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
            $scope.modal.element.modal();
        });
    }

    $scope.saveUser = function () {
        if ($scope.Users.editMode) {
            $scope.Users.update($scope.Users.selected).then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                ngNotify.set(($translate.instant('success_updated_saja')), {
                    type: 'success',
                    position: 'bottom',
                    duration: 1000
                });
                $element.modal('hide');
            });
        } else {
            $scope.Users.create($scope.Users.selected).then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);

                ngNotify.set(($translate.instant('success_created_saja')), {
                    type: 'success',
                    position: 'bottom',
                    duration: 1000
                });
                $element.modal('hide');
            });
        }
    }

    $scope.removeUser = function () {
        $scope.Users.delete($scope.Users.selected).then(function (data) {
            $element.modal('hide');
            $state.go("app.users");
        });
    }

    $scope.selectClient = function (id) {
        $scope.selectedClient = id;
    }

    $scope.filterList = function (contact) {
        if ($scope.selectedClient != 0 && $scope.selectedClient != contact.client) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($scope.filterDirectory) {
            return contact.name.indexOf($scope.filterDirectory) == 0;
        }

        return true;
    }

});
```

As you can see, I handle the objects by fetching (GET) them, then push them (new API) and then, add the functions that should handle each of them. Hope it works

Regards

Comment: ohh so you always avoid update?, also using save dont create a new element?, rather than just modifying it? thanks for answering

Comment: Note that I'm using $.save, instead of .save, $.save is object specific and expects its API endpoint to handle an update when ID is passed i.e. /users will create a user, while /user/{userid} will update an existing user with id "userid". Also please note that for it to work, each element should be converted to an object using new $resource.(data) so that the object does contain all CRUD methods.

Comment: And also, I speech Spanish natively, in case you would feel more conformable asking in that language please do feel to contact me via Chat if I can be of further help. (I saw the name of your functions)

Comment: thanks a lot pablo, yes i would like to talk with you, where is the chat?

Comment: too bad :(, me podrias explicar como hacer eso que me dijiste, me llamo mucho la atencion, gracias

Comment: Yes, let me grab my Lap Top and I'll upload some code for you

Comment: i find that code a little difficult, does your code use routes  in order to work?, my code is not using routes, just displaying all the elements with its buttons to modify, delete, etc.

Comment: No, I use interaction thru controllers.

Comment: Thank you. Let me add  some examples of the way I use the service on the controller.

Comment: i really aprecciate your help, i really do, but i dont understand your code, is there a way you can help me using my kind of logic, or my code :(

Comment: Of course. Post your full source so that I can check it out or upload it to plunkr and send a link.

Comment: I need to see the menuService to see the way you are handling. What are you using for the backend?

Comment: The problem with your code is that you have not defined the "Update" method to use on your service. You are trying to do use the approach I poresented (API and Resource Object based). Try defining an update method.

Comment: this part not?    this.getPlatillos = function() {
            return $resource(baseURL + "/platillos/:id", null, {"update":{method:"PUT"}});
        };

Comment: Yes, sorry. Haven't used that approach for a very long time. You should replace update to save. Take a look at this link. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: No problem. We all start somewhere. Don't give up on your coding. Saludos desde Mexico.

Comment: tienes facebook?, me gustaria agregarte, sabes mucho, quisiera aprender un poco de lo que tu sabes

Comment: Si, puedes agregarme como adoue.p